# wordpress shortcodes

Tags: php, wordpress, themes, blogs, shortcode

Hello everyone i'm new to wordpress and trying to learn more about it , well the thing is that i installed a new theme to my blog and it seems everything works fine except the shortcodes functionality, and i don't know why or where should i look for that problem this is a picture to my admin posting page it shows that i choosed the button short code and nothing happen no parameters to fill in and even when i press the send to editor button nothing happen , please help me to find out my problem :

the picture :
[image: http://tinypic.com/r/a3ppph/6]

Comment: This doesn't look like a programming problem but rather something that has to do with Wordpress configuration, try asking your question here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: maybe [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) you can get help.

Comment: Are you using this Plugin? http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/shortcode-generator/. It hasn't been updated long time. Might not work.

Comment: i'm not sure what plugin it used it's a built in with the theme if someone please can help i can give him my admin access info to check what's wrong , i really need this to work

Comment: and the plugin seems to work fine because whenever i write the code manually it works

Comment: If it's built into the theme you should contact the theme's author, especially if it's a paid theme.

Answer (score 0):

There are posts online that complain about the Shortcode Generator not working.  You should first turn on debug in your wordpress config wp-config.php and see if there are errors being logged.

The best solution is to learn how to add shortcodes manually, it's easy [myshortcode]...[/myshortcode]

Comment: Here's [one of those posts](http://kaptinlin.com/support/discussion/1624/shortcode-generator-doesnt-work/p1)

Comment: I think it's not from the plagin , because i can write the same code manually in the posts and it's working but the problem is when i choose any short code from the dropdown list it doesn't show me any paramaters fileds it's like no event get fired at all

Comment: From what you have said it appears that the shortcode is working, but the generator is not.  Have you checked for logged errors? Are you running the right version of PHP?

Comment: edit your wp-config to set DEBUG to true, the errors will appear in your browser.  Be sure to have a backup for the config file as editing errors can make your site inaccessible.

Comment: i enabled the DEBUGGING Mode and this is the error messages i got , anyone have any idea it looks like the theme using a function that's not supported anymore my WP version is 3.5 , and it's clear that all the problems are in the functions.php file : http://tinypic.com/r/1zxgeb/6

Comment: None of those errors look to be related to the Shortcode Generator.  They are mostly deprecation notices, which shouldn't impact the site at present but indicate you theme needs to be updated.  What theme are you using?  Have you tried running the shortcode generator with debugging on?